# Turn cursor into hand when hovering above <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

Tags: css, flash

Inside a HTML5 page I have this thing:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" data="do stuff and get an image to use as an icon" class="my_class">
```

Inside `my_class` I defined `cursor: pointer;`, but when hovering above the swf object image icon the cursor shows the default arrow, not the hand. I already tried adding `!important` to my css class... Any other ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.my_class:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```